# TypeError: google.cloudbilling is not a function

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-apis-explorer, google-cloud-billing

I'm trying to do this on Google Cloud Function but I got the Error message as the title. and I check the source code on goolgeapis, I can't find the `cloudbilling` function, but I saw a function `cloudbilling_v1`, what the i miss?
https://cloud.google.com/billing/reference/rest/v1/projects/updateBillingInfo

My googleapis version is '40.0.0'.

Comment: Using the code from the link you provided, change var google = require('googleapis'); to const {google} = require('googleapis');

Comment: Please let me know if it works for you and/or, if that's not the code you're running, please provide the minimal reproducible code.

Comment: @Maxim it's working. Thanks

Comment: It turned out to be an error in the documentation. I provided an answer to your post for further visibility. Although the changes have already been reflected in the docs.

Answer (score 0):

It is an error in the documentation. Change `var google = require('googleapis');` to `const {google} = require('googleapis');`.